# How to write in txt file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, input, save, activex

I want to save something in txt file by using JavaScipt

```
<input type="date" id="date1">
  <script>
  var a=document.getElementByid("date1");
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("Test.txt", 8, true);
    fh.WriteLine("Something");
    fh.Close();

  </script>
```

I tried this but it's not working. My main idea is to get value form input and save it in `Test.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can't; not reliably, cross-browser. JavaScript in the browser (where you're clearly using it) runs in a sandbox and is not allowed to access the local filesystem. Some older versions of IE will allow you to use the `FileSystemObject` in the way shown in your question, but only with masses of security warnings, and modern versions don't allow it at all.

The [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and [FileSystem API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) allow limited *reading* from files in the file system, but writing is still a work in progress.

Your best bet is to post a form to your server, probably with `target="_blank"`, and have the server respond with a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Test.txt` header and the file data, which will cause the browser to ask the user where to save it.